# Content aggregator with Python

Tags: python, reddit

I am trying to build a personal content aggregator and I started off with Reddit.
My aim is to build something that is designed properly for this task so that I could add more sources and delivery options easily.

If possible, I'd like you to focus your reviews on the design of the code (any other feedback is welcome as well)

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
import praw
import os

CLIENT_ID = os.environ.get('REDDIT_CLIENT_ID')
CLIENT_SECRET = os.environ.get('REDDIT_CLIENT_SECRET')


class Source(ABC):
    
    @abstractmethod
    def connect(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def fetch(self):
        pass


class RedditSource(Source):

    def connect(self):
        self.reddit_con = praw.Reddit(client_id=CLIENT_ID,
                     client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
                     grant_type_access='client_credentials',
                     user_agent='script/1.0')
        return self.reddit_con

    def fetch(self):
        pass


class RedditHotProgramming(RedditSource):
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.reddit_con = super().connect()
        self.hot_submissions = []

    def fetch(self, limit: int):
        for submission in self.reddit_con.subreddit('programming').hot(limit=limit):
            self.hot_submissions.append(submission)

    def __repr__(self):
        urls = []
        for submission in self.hot_submissions:
            urls.append(vars(submission)['url'])
        return '\n'.join(urls)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET
    reddit_top_programming = RedditHotProgramming()
    reddit_top_programming.fetch(limit=10)
    print(reddit_top_programming)
```

I am also pondering on how should I add a delivery module. as of now, my idea was to create a separate class with the strategy pattern in mind to allow different types of deliveries (email, IM, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class tree is kind of scrambled. It doesn't make sense to have an abstract `connect` - not all sources will need connection, and any connection can just happen in the constructor.

`RedditSource.connect` is confused because it both sets a member - when best practices discourage setting new members outside of `__init__` - and returns it, only for the return value to be used in `super().connect()` - only to overwrite the same member variable. I would refactor this so that there is no `connect` method at all; and `RedditSource.__init__` instantiates the `praw.Reddit` object.

Is the return value of `hot()` a source-agnostic type? I suspect not. It looks like your conversion from source-specific to source-agnostic data occurs in your `__repr__`. This is a problem because the type of `hot_submissions` will differ from the type of a similar member in a different source. One solution is

- Don't have a `hot_submissions` member at all, making the source class a source only and not a repository of data;
- Do not mutate `self` during `fetch`;
- Yield submissions from your `fetch`; and
- have the format of those submissions be whatever common format you care about from all of your sources, non-specific to Reddit. If you only care about a URL list, the return type of `fetch` should be an iterable of URLs with conversion happening in `fetch` or a subroutine.

Do not include `assert` in production code as it can be trivially disabled.